# Regex lookaround doesn't match from the beginning of a line. Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I'm parsing text with ingredients for a recipe, and sometimes there is something like '1 can (21 Oz.) of beans' there.

Firstly I'm looking for numbers in a line, and then - look around every exact number to figure out what is measure for it.

Everything works fine, till the numbers end similar - for example, here is 1 can and 21 oz., and my previous lookaround

```
(?<=1)[ ]*[a-zA-Z]*
```

finds two words for '1': 'can' and 'oz'.

But I need to find every word after pure '1', not '21'. For this case It have to find just 'can' (without 'oz'), and I tried to remove everything with digits before it:

```
(?<=[^\d]1)[ ]*[a-zA-Z]*
```

and it works fine if 1 can is not at the beginning of a line... For example, in these two lines:

1 can (21 Oz.) # it matched nothing

21 oz (1 can) # matched ' can'

If I'll add a space at the first line (before '1 can') it works fine as well... So there is something strange just at the beginning.

What is the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it 100% correct, but it works for every word after '1'

```
(?<!\d)1[ ]*([a-zA-Z]+)
```